# Slider, Works with IE, mobile devices not chrome

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I have installed a slider into a website, it is viewable with IE, mobile devices ETC, but it does not work with chrome. Is this as simple as using an IF statement to sort this?

You can see what I mean at http://www.test.hdwebdesigns.co.uk/SIM/ you will see it works in IE and mobile devices but not chrome.

I am unable to upload to JSFiddle, so I have uploaded a RAR file of the site here http://www.test.hdwebdesigns.co.uk/SIM/SIM.rar

Comment: What prevents you from creating a jsfiddle?

Comment: The PC keeps crashing

Comment: If you post the javascript and html in this question, we could help you out.

Comment: hmmm, works for me in chrome 31.0.1650.63 m. Which version are you having problems in?

Comment: Works for me too on Chrome. Usually, it is vice versa. It works on Chrome but not on any IE :)